# Get value of element in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

In a section of my code, I have the following problem:

I need to access the value of a li element:

```
const elements = element.map((element) =>
     <li>{element}</li>
     );
```

```
<ul>
<!--I need access to this value-->
{elements}
 </ul>
```

**example:**

```
<li>mark</li>
```

**value: mark**

Comment: don't you still have access to element and can just lock up your value? Can you please clarify what you want and why element[0] for example is not accessible?

Comment: @ian the user clicks on the list item and depending on that click, the following actions are deterimined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access the name of the element through a click event handler like so:

```
  const names = [
    'Mark',
    'John',
  ];

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    const { name } = event.target;

    // you now have access to name
  };

...other code

  return (
    <ul>
      {names.map((name) => <li name={name} onClick={handleClick}>{name}</li>)}
    </ul>
  );
```

OR

```
  const names = [
    'Mark',
    'John',
  ];

  const handleClick = (name) => {
    // you now have access to name
  };

...other code

  return (
    <ul>
      {names.map((name) => <li onClick={() => handleClick(name)}>{name}</li>)}
    </ul>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
const handleClick = e => {
    let value = e.target.innerHTML; // Returns HTML + String
    // OR
    value = e.target.innerText; // Returns Just String Value
}

const elements = element.map((element) =>
     <li onClick={handleClick}>{element}</li>
);
```